# how to escape brakets in java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

> [1359873374000,281197568],[1360044062000,1206052864],[1360068648000,991623168]

How can I extract each item like `[1359873374000,281197568]` with regex?

I have written this code, but it does not work:

```
String[] parts = mainstr.split("\\[[0-9],[0-9]\\]");
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse JSON? There are Java libraries that do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **split** it with

```
(?<=\\]),(?=\\[)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches `[1,2]`. You have to add a multiplier:

```
"\\[[0-9]+,[0-9]+\\]"
```

Edit:
I don't think `split()` will do what you want. Take a look at the [Matcher Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Solution with Matcher class:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String sourceString = "[1359873374000,281197568],[1360044062000,1206052864],[1360068648000,991623168]";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[[0-9]+,[0-9]+\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sourceString);

while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
  System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

This will give you every occurance of the number pairs. If you want to use the numbers separately, you can catch them like this: `"\\[([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\\]"`. You will have to extend the example though.

Comment: that would eat everthing except `,`

Comment: As I said, `split()` might be the wrong function for the task.

Answer (score 1):

`[0-9]` matches exactly one digit.  If you want to match sequence of digits, use `[0-9]*`.  If you want to match non-empty sequence of digits, use `[0-9]+`.  In your case you probably need to do `"\\[[0-9]+,[0-9]+\\]"`, or, which is the same, `"\\[\\d+,\\d+\\]"` because `\d` means "digit" in Java regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect as it loses some of the brackets, but at least the numbers are intact and correctly grouped:

```
String[] parts = mainstr.split("\\D,\\D");
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to split on '],[', not on the whole pattern you are searching. Try this:

```
String[] parts = mainstr.split("\\\\],\\\\["); // Never sure when to use double or quadruple slashes.
```

After that, you might need to replace the brackets.